# Using Cowplot for a list of plots using paste0

Tags: r, paste, cowplot

I have a list of ggplots from 1:10 called `plot_1`,`plot_2`....`plot_10`.

I wanted to use cowplot to display all plots together.

How can I use `plot.grid()` to call all plots? i.e I want to write something like

```
plot.grid(paste0("plot",1:10))
```

but this doesn't work - I get the error:

> Error in ggplot_to_gtable(x) : 
>     Argument needs to be of class "ggplot" or "gtable"*

Answer (score 14):

```
plot_grid(plotlist=mget(paste0("pl_", 1:10)))
```

In the help information about plot_grid, it says you can use `plotlist` to provide a list of plots. The `mget` function gives you a way to search multiple objects by name (in this case the plots), which are generated by the `paste0` function.

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Comment: I added an explanation.